# Is it possible to embed QGIS layer styles in a Spatialite database?

Tags: qgis, spatialite, style

Spatialite is a great alternative to shapefiles - but how could I store the QGIS layer style together with the data so that it has a default style?

For a shapefile I would just save a `[name].qml` with the `[name].shp` file set, and it would style by default. Any equivalent for Spatialite?

Comment: Would you consider revising the scope of your question to include storage of not just `.qml`, but also the entire  `.qgs` file?  I've been thinking of an entire QGIS project -- data, style, and settings -- in a single, cross-platform file.  Yes, please.

Comment: Currently the .qps file contains styles and settings, but **not data**. I can't imagine you would want all data stored in each project file. That would potentially make each qps huge (think aerial imagery), and duplicate copies of data over and over.

Comment: Regarding the original question, work is being done[1] to save layer styles to a PostGIS database. I'd like to hope that spatialite will follow soon after.  [1]https://github.com/qgis/Quantum-GIS/pull/522

Comment: @Micha Note that I'm not proposing that storing a project in sqLite would preclude QGIS from connecting to other data sources.  I use a lot of project-specific data that would do well to be contained in one file.  DropBox anyone?

Comment: @Scro, no, I wanted to just limit the question to the specifics of the layer style, but getting the .qgs file in there is an attractive idea!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This feature was added to the [master branch of QGIS about 4 months ago](https://github.com/qgis/Quantum-GIS/commits/master/?author=Emilio%20Loi), but *only* for PostgreSQL/PostGIS databases, not Spatialite. The series of commits could be squashed down to provide a concise view of how to add such support for Spatialite. [Please submit a feature request](http://hub.qgis.org/wiki/quantum-gis/Bugreports), and link to this page.

**Interesting side note**, Spatialite 4.1+ offers [a new storage blob, XmlBlob](https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/wiki?name=XmlBlob+and+VirtualXPath). There has been talk of making Spatialite the default vector format (not shapefile) for QGIS. And, there is talk/plans for allowing many aspects of a project to be stored in a database, including the .qgs file, metadata and styles (I believe @nathan-w may be working on this). This is the reason the File menu was recently renamed to Project, since a database connection could be the sole source of a project.

The new XmlBlob offers a nice solution for these geo resources, and I for one, would like to see a simple solution for storing whole projects, with data, metadata, styles and symbols in a single, multi-platform db file (i.e. Spatialite):

- [SLD/SE Styling support](https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/wiki?name=SLD/SE+Styling)
- [ISO Metadata support](https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/wiki?name=ISO+Metadata)
- [XPath support](https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/wiki?name=VirtualXPath-intro)

Comment: Shame there's no option yet - but very encouraging news on the potential in 4.1 and adding this as default for QGIS.

Answer (score 6):

now it'a available in Master and will be officially available in Qgis 2.4

http://pvanb.wordpress.com/2014/05/15/saving-layer-styles-to-your-spatialite-database/

Comment: and in master will be available also delete... PR under revision